# sending file to server throught action in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, xml

Hi how would I send a file to a server through action in Javascript
///

```
<script> 
function go() 
{
    document.MyForm.action = "http://"+document.Config.IP.value+":"+document.Config.PORT.value
    document.MyForm.submit();

}
</script>
```

so instead of sending the form i send the FILE (root.xml)

how would i go about doing this?

Comment: In no way, only use html tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you *can* do this with JavaScript, but it's difficult and not widely supported. The new [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) allows your browser-based code ringfenced access to specific files.

But by far the more useful, and universally-supported, mechanism is to have a `file` input in a form that gets submitted:

```
<form action="/your/page/that/handles/receipt/">
<input type='file' name='theFile'>
</form>
```

If the user selects a file, when that form is submitted (which you can do via `Form#submit` if you like) the file is transmitted with it. No special handling involved.

Comment: what if i dont want the user to chose a file? I want it to be Home.xml which is in a specific folder and nothing else?

Comment: there should be another attribute under FORM that I can use right? but im not sure like

Comment: @suffix: You can't, the user has to select the file. You can see what file they've selected by looking at the input's `value` property (the name will be real, the path you see will be fake) and tell them that that's not the right file, but you can't set it for them. JavaScript in the browser has only very, very limited access to the user's filesystem -- which makes sense, of course. Even using the File API, which gives you much more access than before, it still starts with the user identifying the file.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function go() {
    document.getElementById('file_upload_form').onsubmit=function() {
        document.getElementById('file_upload_form').target = 'upload_target'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: is file upload from the XML file?

Answer (score 0):

You need file input in your form.

For a file upload to take place:
.The INPUT type=file element must be enclosed within a FORM element.
.A value must be specified for the NAME attribute of the INPUT type=file element.
.The METHOD attribute of the FORM element must be set to post.
.The ENCTYPE attribute of the FORM element must be set to multipart/form-data.

Then use your js

Comment: but i dont want the USER to SELECT the file i want the file "home.xml" to be sent and nothing else